# Phonegap push notification plugin with iOs

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm using phonegap-plugin-push to send push notifications to Android devices.

I'm trying to figure out how to send notification to iOs.

I've registered at https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=ios&cntapi=gcm&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fios%2Fclient&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20GCM%20Support&%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue

I'get token at client app same way as in Android:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
        android: {
            senderID: "5993...475"
        },
        ios: {
            alert: "true",
            badge: true,
            sound: 'false'
        },
        windows: {}
    });

push.on('registration', function(data) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/save-token/',
        data: {token: data.registrationId},
        success: function (json) {

        }
    });


});
```

After I get client's token, I try to send'em push notification:

```
$to = ModelGcmTokens::getInstance()->getToken($userId);

$API_KEY = 'AIzaS...HcEYC346zQ';


        $message = array(
            'data' => array(
                'title' => ($title) ? $title : 'Test!',
                'message' => $message
            ),
            'to' => $to
        );

        $message = json_encode($message);

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message);


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Authorization:key={$API_KEY}",
            "Content-Type:application/json",
        ));

        // receive server response ...
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

        curl_close ($ch);

        // further processing ....
        if ($server_output == "OK") {

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
```

Google cloud messaging responds with **InvalidRegistration** error:

```
{"multicast_id":4701637331500989392,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

As I googled this error - it's said that I got client's token wrong.
But I get it with excat same script as on Android. And it works on Android.

The only difference, that I see - is format of the token:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how do I get push plugin working on iOs? What's wrong with iOs token and how do I supposed to send messages to GCM, to be received by iOs?

Thanks a lot in advance for any advice. I'm really stuck.

Comment: Apple push has different environments for sending pushes, one for development and one for production. If you obtain the dev token and send it on the prod environment or vice versa then it won't work. Do you know which environment you are trying to send the pushes to iOS on?

Comment: well, I got production key and send it to production server

Comment: And I dont really understand how do I get 'production' or 'developepment' tokens. I get them through magic of plugin, when it sends some signal to GCM servers and gets token from there. What kind of token is it - I dont know. But supposed to be production since I've uploaded production p12 key to GCM servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are calling the init method requests the registration ID from APNS not GCM. If you read the documentation on [GCM on iOS](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#ios-gcm-support) at the phonegap-plugin-push repository you will see that init needs to be called like this:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    android: {
        senderID: "5993...475"
    },
    ios: {
        senderID: "5993...475",
        gcmSandbox: true,
        alert: "true",
        badge: true,
        sound: 'false'
    },
    windows: {}
});
```

If the iOS options has a `senderID` it will register with GCM.

Also, I notice in the response to one of the comments you don't know the difference between `production` and `development` environments on APNS. Well, you really need to read up on this. On iOS devices the APNS environment is different depending if you `production` and `development` environment. IF you setup your app as `development` and you send a push through `production` it will never arrive at your device.

Now you may be asking why I'm talking about APNS. That's because when you use GCM on iOS you would send your push message to GCM which then will forward your message to the APNS servers and finally to your device.

Comment: Thanks A lot man. This phrase `If the iOS options has a senderID it will register with GCM.` - so simple and sooooo important. Thanks again!

Comment: Simon, I'd really appreciate if you take a look at next problem ; I dont get any registrationId now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268507/gcm-registrationid-is-not-received-on-phonegap-push-plugin